# How do i introduce certain restrictions to text in C#

Tags: c#, regex

I'm creating a C# program that reads a string of words from an xml file, creates a page of text and writes it into a txt file. However I'm trying to introduce restrictions that will stop a word from being put on the page of text if it breaks any of these 3 rules.

1. only lower case letters a-z can be used
2. Each word must contain a vowel, words with 5 letters or more must contain 2
3. All vowels must appear in alphabetical order i.e. words like beat are rejected as e comes before a

I understand that to do this, I need to somehow read each character per line but I don't know how to do this or implement these 3 restrictions into code

```
XML example input file
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<pageinput>
<format>Fill</format>       //determines what format I want the txt page to be
<wrap>8</wrap>              //this limits how many letters per word
<words>abc 8Ug antert bonnfk beat e</words>     //the words to be read
</pageinput>
```

Expected Output in txt File
abc
antert
e

Comment: Look into regular expressions.

Comment: @AB2515 put some code, what have you already done?

Comment: Example text and desired output wont harm either

Comment: okay, I've added the examples but my program is in multiple classes and I don't think it will fit

Comment: We don't need the whole program, just the part that applies your rules to a word.  Have you tried anything yet?  This is absolute beginner level stuff, and it looks like you're asking us to do your homework for you.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a lover of regular expressions, so I'm gonna post some Linq and basic solutions:

```
public static class Extensions {
    static readonly char[] vowels = { 'a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u' };

    //#1
    public static bool IsLowerCase( this string word ){
        return word.All( c => c >= 'a' && c <= 'z' );
    }

    //#2
    public static bool ContainsVowels( this string word ) {
        int count = word.Count( c => vowels.Contains( c ) );

        return ( count >= 1 && word.Length < 5 ) || ( count > 1 && word.Length >= 5 );
    }

    //#3 
    public static bool AreVowelsOrdered( this string word ) {
        char? lastVowel = null;
        foreach ( char c in word ) {
            if ( vowels.Contains( c ) ) {
                if ( lastVowel == null || c > lastVowel )
                    lastVowel = c;
                else if ( c < lastVowel )
                    return false;                 
            }
        }

        return true;
    }
}
```

Then use them like:

```
( "example" ).IsLowerCase( ); //true
```

You can optimize them a lot by merging everything into a unique loop, and this is just a point to start from.